# Refer to ViewNavigator in Code

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I need to call navigator.pushView from an .as file in an AIR mobile project. But since I'm in an .as file and not in the .mxml file, how do I get access to the ViewNavigator?

EDIT: I don't have this set up as a tabbed navigation project; my root is ViewNavigatorApplication.  I found this as a suggested solution:

```
 parent.parentApplication.vn.pushView(MyViewClass)
```

But there are two problems with this. First, it assumes there's a ViewNavigator named vn. I don't see how to name the ViewNavigator, or even where it can be found. Second, I introspected the parents of my .as class and in order to get to parentApplication I would have to do:

```
this.parent.parent.parent.parentApplication.vn.pushView(MyViewClass);
```

Note that 'this' is also *not* the view I want to push. I just want to push a View.mxml class from my .as class.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.navigator.pushView(NewView)
```